# Shorten url adds additional attribute : _branch_match_id which is causing issue in opening S3 presigned URL

Tags: branch.io

I uploaded PDF file into S3 bucket using Java, generated presigned url and shared that URL to customer. Now we have a requirement to share shorten url instead of S3 presigned url. I used branch.io to get shorten url. When I open that shorten url then it expands to actual url, but it contains additional attribute in the URL like &_branch_match_id=768717994353327033. So, it is causing an issue like "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method"

Comment: Hi, Branch Match ID is automatically appended when you open links and is required for attribution. Could you please share the use case of uploading Branch Deep links to S3 bucket?

Comment: I did not upload links into s3 bucket, uploading PDF files into that and then generating links for stored files. This URL is very lengthy URL and it is very hard to share it with user. So created shorten link by branch.io, but it is appending branch match id in the url.  Sample URL : https://XXXXX.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/784100_010742_history_statement.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200706T072620Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXX%2F20200706%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=XXXXXXX&_branch_match_id=768717994353327033

Comment: Please note that Branch isn't a link shortener platform and instead is a deep-linking platform. I am still unsure how you are shortening these links. With that being said, match_id will be appended to all Branch links and is required for deep linking matching.

Comment: If that still doesn't help please drop an email to support@branch.io